# iterate through ListView and delete list items based on their content

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I have a `ListView` setup which I dynamically add items to with each item having different data. One of the pieces of data is a time/date which is shown in a `TextView` in my custom List item layout. In the onResume() method of my `Fragment` I would like to remove items that have a date shown which is before the current date.

The List item layout is as follows:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/pi_rl"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/pi_tv_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/pi_tv_date"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/pi_tv_title"
        android:textSize="24sp" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

The idea that I had to solve this was to create a loop, which iterated through all the items checking the content of the date TextView for each item. Then, if the date was before the current date, it would remove the item.

I am currently able to delete items based on there position, **but I can't work out how to delete individual list items if they have a certain content**.

This is what I have so far:

```
@Override
    public void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();

        int items = DataModel.getInstance().getPendingItemList().size(); // Number of items in the list

        if (items > 0) {
            for (int i = 1; i <= items; i++) { // This loops through all my items. Do I want to use position instead?
                Log.i("for loop", "" + i);

// This doesn't work because it tries to get the content for all the items not just one.

                TextView tv_date = (TextView) getView()
                        .findViewById(R.id.pi_tv_date);

                CharSequence c = tv_date.getText(); // Causes force close

                                 // Here I will have my if(date shown != current date){
//deleteItem
//}

            }

        }

    }
```

**EDIT:** This is my adapter code:

```
private class PendingAdapter extends BaseAdapter { // This happens whenever
                                                    // onCreate is called.

    private List<Map<String, Object>> mPendingItemList;

    public PendingAdapter() {
        mPendingItemList = DataModel.getInstance().getPendingItemList();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mPendingItemList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return mPendingItemList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (null == convertView) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(
                    R.layout.pending_item, null);
            // Log.i("convertView", "was null");
        }

        TextView tv_title = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.pi_tv_title);

        TextView tv_date = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.pi_tv_date);

        HashMap<String, String> itemDataHashMap = (HashMap<String, String>) getItem(position);

        tv_title.setText(itemDataHashMap.get("planet"));
        tv_date.setText(itemDataHashMap.get("date"));

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

**EDIT 2:**

As per `Ali AlNoaimi`'s answer, I have added this inside my Adapter:

```
public void refreshMyAdapter() {

            if(mPendingItemList.size() > 0) {
            List<Map<String, Object>> newPendingList = mPendingItemList;

            for (int i = 0; i < mPendingItemList.size(); i++) {
                Map<String, Object> item = mPendingItemList.get(i);

                TextView tv_title = (TextView) histView
                        .findViewById(R.id.pi_tv_title);

                String s_title;

                s_title = tv_title.getText().toString();

                 Log.i("s_title", s_title);

                if(s_title == "foo") {

                    newPendingList.remove(item);
                }


            }

            mPendingItemList = newPendingList;
        }

        }
```

and this to the `onResume()`:

```
@Override
    public void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();

        final Handler handler = new Handler(); new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                while(true) {

                    handler.post(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            simpleAdpt.refreshMyAdapter();
                            simpleAdpt.notifyDataSetChanged();

                        }

                    });



                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(500);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }

        }).start();
```

This still does not work.

**FINAL EDIT:** `Ali AlNoaimi`'s answer did work, I was just comparing strings incorrectly.

I hope this makes sense! Thank you

Comment: Please post your adapter code, and where exactly your onResume exists

Comment: @AliAlNoaimi I have added the adapter code. The `Fragment` is part of a `NavigationDrawer`, so I am overriding the onResume() in the fragment

Comment: One very general programming point: almost always when you go through a list (of anything) deleting things: always go **backwards from the end** so you avoid stepping on yourself.  Hope it helps some new reader!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this method to your adapter:

```
public void refreshMyAdapter() {

    private List<Map<String, Object>> newPendingList;

    for (int i = 0; i < mPendingItemList.size(); i++) {
        Map<String, Object> item = mPendingItemList.get(i);

        if(it matches) {
            newPendingList.add(item);
        }


    }

    mPendingItemList = newPendingList;
}
```

and in your main activity, fragment

```
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while(true) {

                handler.post(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        yourPendingAdapter.refreshMyAdapter();
                        yourPendingAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                    }

                });



                try {
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

    }).start();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I am having a problem where it is not deleting the item even if it matches

Comment: Because you are using singleton class :) :)

Comment: @Anis Yes, my DataModel is a singleton class (I think), but seeing as I am able to add different data to individual list items this should not be a problem. Surely I should just be able to check a certain TextView in each item and then if it matches what I want, then I can do something.  The main question is: How to I check through a TextView in each item?

Comment: Save the TextView values in an array or map defined at the adapter class, just like mPendingItemList, and then iterate through it and use the example above to delete the matching items.

Comment: The values are already stored in a Hashmap. This is shown in my adapter code, as I use ` HashMap<String, String> itemDataHashMap = (HashMap<String, String>) getItem(position);

        tv_title.setText(itemDataHashMap.get("planet"));` Would you be able to show how I could use this in the refreshMyAdapter() please?

Comment: inside the iteration in the first example, the variable "i" is the position.

Comment: @AliAlNoaimi It still does't work unfortunately.  I will add my version of your code to the question.  I had to initialize newPendingList so I made it equal to mPendingItemList.

Comment: @RiThBo I believe it's because of TextView tv_title = (TextView) histView.findViewById(R.id.pi_tv_title); make sure histView is the right view for the current item and that it's not null.

Comment: @AliAlNoaimi Yes, your right histView is the main fragment view not the item view.  How would I be able to use the correct view.  I tried to make `convertView` (which is the correct view) a global variable, but I then get a NullPointerException presumably because convertView is null.

Comment: yourAdapter.getView(........) in your case, inside refreshMyAdapter just getView(........).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36199/discussion-between-rithbo-and-ali-alnoaimi)

Comment: I found out why it wasn't working! I was comparing strings using `==` instead of `.equals()`. I have marked your answer as correct. Thanks for helping :-)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you understand how `ListView` works. A `ListView` is the visual representation of the data in your adapter, so you should never try to edit, add or delete views of a `ListView` directly, but instead edit the data and then call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on your adapter.

The `ListView` will then check for changes in your adapter's data and refresh the views accordingly.

For your specific problem, it means that you should work directly with `mPendingItemList`, find the items that have a specific content, remove them and then call `notifyDataSetChanged()`.

Comment: I understand how to update the ListView, but I would like to check  the data for each item and the delete it if the data matches what I want.

Comment: How would I "find the items that have a specific content"?

Comment: That's basic Java, you iterate through `mPendingItemList`, call `get("date")` (for example) on each item and test if the value is what you want. If it's not, you remove the item. At the end of this operation you just call `notifyDataSetChanged()`.

Comment: Thanks - one last question: How do I iterate through the mPendingItemList? Would you do it the same way as Ali AlNoaimi?

Comment: Yes, or with an iterator but it's not very important.

Answer (score 0):

Bedst way is to remove the items in the ArrayList you used when creating the adapter then call `notifyDataSetChanged();` on the adabter to update the listview.

Answer (score 0):

to have a coherent implementation, keep data processing on the DataModel.
add to DataModel class this method:

```
public void clearObsoleteItems(){
    //TODO: add you implementation to clear the obsolete items from the List of items holded by the singleton class. 

}
```

add on your adapter class PendingAdapter a setter for items list:

```
public void setPendingItemList(List<Map<String, Object>> mPendingItemList) {
this.mPendingItemList = mPendingItemList;
notifyDataSetChanged();
```

}

from the activity onResume call:

```
DataModel.getInstance().clearObsoleteItems();

mAdapter.setPendingItemList(DataModel.getInstance().getPendingItemList());
```

Comment: Thanks Anis, but the problem is how do I know which items are obsolete and which are not?  To find out, I need to get the data from a `TextView` in each item.  If the data matches what I want I remove it.  I have a method to delete the obsolete items already, so I just need a way of getting the info from the TextView of each item.

Comment: The data on TextViews are filled from your DataModel, so you List, returned by DataModel.getInstance().getPendingItemList() holds all your data, just iterate on it, remove obsolete and update it. after that you notify the list to redraw... hope it helps.